# Two lengths of 12/2 romex to substitute for 10/2

Tags: electrical, wiring, wire

Can I run 2 lengths of 12/2 romex 100 feet to substitute for a single run of 10/2? I'm not needing to meet code, just trying to get 120 v at 20 amps to my shop with as little light dimming as possible. Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: If your structure burned because you installed sub-code wiring and your insurance company denied your claim, would you be upset?

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I'm not needing to meet code or comply with insurance regulations. Did you have a real answer? Is it a matter of just multiplying the voltage or will amperage be divided or what? I'm looking for information along those lines, not insurance or code related.

Comment: So, I'll take that as a "no". But the reason I asked is because a lot of people don't think about the ramifications of ignoring code.

Comment: You DO need to meet code. It isn't about dealing with the man, it's about DOING IT SAFELY

Comment: Adding to the chorus;  don't do stupid things  just because you can.

Comment: This sets up the possibility of a parallel current path. You put it in and for some reason someone is injured or dead. At this point I think you would worry about code. So it’s not just against code if something goes wrong and someone is hurt believe me the insurance company is going to protect themselves by throwing you under the buss.

Answer (score 4):

### You only need one run of 12/2, so why waste money?

12/2 is *already legal for 20A* so you're all set.

At 100' you will have 0.2% voltage drop per amp, or 4% drop if you redline the circuit at 20A, which you should not do, as a rule; you should only plan to run 16A (80%).   **You do not need a wire size bump for voltage drop** at 100', and your run is actually 65' so you are all set. Figure on 0.13% voltage drop per amp. So at 20A 2.6V drop, no big deal.

### For anti-dimming, use LEDs or fluorescents *with modern ballasts*

Specifically look for LEDs or fluorescent ballasts made for multi-voltage 100-240V (world voltages).  Those will automatically adjust to voltage "on the fly" so dimming will be minimal/nonexistent; the device will simply treat a startup sag as "oh, we're in Japan now ok".

### Common 15A receptacles can only be on 15A or 20A circuits.

As soon as you put a 25A or 30A breaker on it, you can't have receptacles anymore.  Unless you feed that circuit to a subpanel and distribute it to one or more 15/20A circuits.

### Every breaker is dual thermal/magnetic.

They all have a permissive curve allowing some seconds for a 200% load, some minutes for a 1.25x load, and instant trip for a 1000% load.

If you want that feature local to the shed, feel free to install a **subpanel**. This can be fed with 120v (mine is). You can then use a 30A breaker to get full use out of the #10 wire, and local breakers of appropriate sizes for the circuit.  Subpanels are as cheap as $20 and breakers are typically $5 if you're not subject to AFCI/GFCI requirements.

### There can be only one

One NEC rule is that you can only have one circuit of the same type and usage.  So sticking two 120V circuits out there isn't allowed, unless, say, one of them is controlled by a light switch from the house.

However you can have a 120V circuit and a 240V circuit, 120/240V split-phase circuit, and an MWBC (all at once even).

So have one of your two 120V circuits switched from the house.  Or run a larger 120V circuit and have a subpanel.  Or run a 120V/240V circuit and have a subpanel. Or run a MWBC.

### Wait, what's a MWBC?

It's 2 hots sharing a neutral.  It must be punched down into a 240V common-trip breaker, you can't use a duplex/twin or you'll overload the neutral.

Say you run 12/3 cable and punch it down onto a 240V 20A breaker.  You now have 2 full 20A circuits worth of power available to you.  YOu split one 20A/120V circuit off black and white, and the other 20A/120V circuit off red and white.  Great for saw on phase 1 and dust collector/lights on phase 2 for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO you can not parallel conductors smaller than 1/0 . This is specifically addressed in the NEC 310.10.H.1.

Answer (score 1):

There are parts of code that are for convenience and some that are for extreme edge cases, but much of code is for common issues that have dangerous consequences.  So, to your question, yes, you can run 2 12/2 cables and use that for a higher amperage, but I really feel like this is one of the actually dangerous things that code happens to forbid.

If any connection is weaker than another, more power will flow over the other wire.  In the worst case, a connection can completely break and there will be no symptoms other than an overheating wire.  It's also going to be very confusing for anyone else that needs to work on the circuit.

Your particular use case seems to be to mitigate voltage drop because a single 12/2 cable can carry 20A safely so the downsides (fire) might not be as big of a deal, but it seems like a lot of downsides for saving $100 on a roll of 10/2.

There might be other reasons to not do this, but it's hard to say because most people would just use the right cable.

Comment: Thank you! I should have posed this as a science experiment instead of a construction application to ire of all the inspectors. I've decided to run two circuits instead of combining them. One for the lights and one for the rest of the shop...each on a 25 amp breaker. None of my equipment will draw more than 20 amps and the run is actually closer to 60 feet. I'm guessing that arrangement will prevent light dimming.

Comment: 25 amps is technically too much for a 12ga wire.  If there is a faulty space heater or short circuit or whatever, the wire will get too hot and could damage insulation and other connectors.  Might not be into "start a fire" range, but something to consider.  Also realize that breakers have a built in time delay and a 20A breaker will let 25A of current pass for a short time before it heats up and trips.

Comment: You've forced me to reconsider. The 12/2 romex was $60 for 250 ft at Lowes, hence the 2 runs. That's what I was hoping to get away with spending. Now, I guess I'll go with 10/2 100 ft. now. I didn't now about a delay in the fuses. Just assumed it was instantaneous. The 10/2 is rated for 20 amps and 2400 watts at 65 ft. These facts, they'll get you ever time. I'm forced to work with very little (like no insurance or licensed electrician), but your information has moved me to splurge. I owe you! Just please don't come to collect :)

Comment: Ha, yea, there are a few questions about breakers here.  They have two methods of working - they have a magnetic immediate disconnect for very high current (think two wires touching, 100's of amps) and then they have a heat based disconnect for lower level over current.  A 20A breaker will let 21A through for an hour or two, but as it gets higher, the time is shorter.  40A might trip it in 15 seconds.  [Here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/62087/43874) is an answer with an actual time curve for a breaker.

Comment: Well, there you go. Now I'm shopping for a thermal circuit breaker, or combo thermal/magnetic if such a thing exists. Some of my tools are inherited from my dad, and some are kind of old. If I happen to forget to unplug something, not unusual, I'm afraid it could develop a high amp "leak", if you know what I mean. This is quite a project. Nerve racking. Initially thought the building would blow over in a breeze. Now learning about circuit breakers. Tying in to the main circuit panel scares me to death. I'd rather get cut than shocked.

Comment: The standard $10 breakers used everywhere are thermal/magnetic.  That's not a special model.

Comment: duh...Thank you again! I've embarrassed myself now. The site has warned me this discussion is too long so I'll stop. You've been a great help, JPhi1618, more than you know! Have a great evening!